# DocuSign - finding a user's User Id

Tags: docusignapi

To give our app permission to update a user's envelopes, they need to go through the OAuth flow and after that, we need their user id.

For my developer account and my demo account, I can find this under Settings > Integrations > Apps and keys. But my client, who has a paying DocuSign account, doesn't have that menu. Is there another way to find the user id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After the user logs in via oauth, use the userinfo endpoint to obtain their user id and the account IDs they have access to.  See https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/

Comment: Hi Larry, thank you for your response. I thought so too, but when I call https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo in the return url after the OAuth, I get an internal server error. I have tried without adding an Authorization Bearer or with adding the url parameter that is added to the return url as an Authorization Bearer, but both give me the same error. Should I post the code I use?

Comment: Ask a new question with subject "Problem calling DocuSign userinfo". Include a trace of your call, error messages, etc. Thank you